# Generate several excel files using apache poi and java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have to generate several excel files, but when using a `for` loop to create the different files, it throws an `EmptyFileException:the supplied file was empty`. The first time it generates an excel file, but later, it throws that exception. I have tried closing the `FileInputStream`, but it did not work.

```
public static void mergeExcelFiles(ArrayList<Employe> employeList, Enterprise enterprise, List<FileInputStream> list) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> cell_formulas = generateCellToFormula();
    File file = null;

    for (int j = 0; j < employeList.size(); j++) {
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = null;
        file = new File(listaEmpleados.get(j).getNombre() + ".xlsx");
        try {
            for (FileInputStream fin : list) {
                XSSFWorkbook b = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
                for (int i = 0; i < b.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                    sheet = book.createSheet(b.getSheetName(i));
                    copySheets(book, sheet, b.getSheetAt(i));

                    }
                }
            }
            setDataWorkerInHoraryModel(book, enterpise, employeList.get(j));
            passWeekendToSheets(book);
            writeFile(book, file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: `XSSFWorkbook b = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);`

Comment: Try debugging list. It seems like there are empty files in there. If so try to check for files that are empty to avoid the exception.

Comment: i use the same list for every excel. 
I fill it before call the mehod with two files

Comment: Rafa, I have edited the question to remove the asking-for-help part (all questions here ask for help answering them!) and the description of what you need it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/EmptyFileException.html

Exception thrown if an Empty (zero byte) file is supplied

```
 for (FileInputStream fin : list) {
                XSSFWorkbook b = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
                for (int i = 0; i < b.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                    sheet = book.createSheet(b.getSheetName(i));
                    copySheets(book, sheet, b.getSheetAt(i));

                    }
                }
            }
```

The list you are passing has file that is 0 bytes.

========= Edited ===========

You are doing FileInputStream fin : list, there will be a lock on that file.

You need to close the inputstream if you want your system resources released back.

fin.close() is what you need, before the next iteration of the forloop.

Comment: @Rafa please post your exception also.

Comment: `org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)`

Comment: but i generate the first excel file with that list. I repeat the process with a for loop and i don´t clean the list or anything

Comment: You have more than 1 file in [LIST]  Maybe the first file is fine...but the second workbook is not. @Rafa

Comment: the first time the program run well, later it crash

Comment: debugged the list and it contains the two files without r problems

Comment: @Rafa Perhaps you are not closing/saving your file in that writeFileMethod?

Comment: `protected static void writeFile(XSSFWorkbook book, File file) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        book.write(out);
        //out.flush();
        out.close();
    }`

Comment: @Rafa try book.close() before out.close();

Comment: Solved. I must close the files after processing them in each iteration. Thank you